# When using Dart I am creating a DOM class on click event. It only picks up the first element, how do I have it fire on all elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dart

I am experimenting with Dart. I have created an on click event like so:
    `query('.numbutton').on.click.add((e) {
      window.alert('click!');
    });`

I have multiple buttons using the class numbutton:
    `<input type="button" class="numbutton" value="1">`
    `<input type="button" class="numbutton" value="2">`
    `<input type="button" class="numbutton" value="3">`

When I click the 1 button an alert pops up that says click! but if I click the 2 or 3 button nothing happens. I have tried this with jQuery and it works just fine:

```
$('.numbutton').click(function(){
   alert('click!');
});
```

What am I missing with DART?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final List<Element> elements = queryAll('.numbutton');
for(Element e in elements) {
    e.on.click.add((e) => print('clicked!'));
}
```

or

```
queryAll('.numbutton').forEach((e) => e.on.click.add((e) => print('NPE-safe one-liner!')));
```